# Getting the object in the Typescript not working (Defining useReducer hook types)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this piece of code in types.ts file,

```
import { CategoryType } from "../../types/CategoryItemCount";
import { ModelErrorType } from "../../types/ModelError";

export const ACTIONS = {
  SET_CATEGORIES: "SET_CATEGORIES",
  ADD_CATEGORIS: "ADD_CATEGORIES",
  UPDATE_CATEGORIES: "UPDATE_CATEGPRIES",
  DELETE_CATEGORIES: "DELETE_CATEGORIES",
  SET_MODEL_ERRORS: "SET_MODEL_ERRORS",
  SENDING_REQUEST: "SENDING_REQUEST",
  REQUEST_COMPLETED: "REQUEST_COMPLETED",
};

export type Action =
  | { type: ACTIONS.SET_CATEGORIES, payload: CategoryType[] }
  | { type: ACTIONS.ADD_CATEGORIES, payload: CategoryType }
  | { type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_CATEGORIES, payload: CategoryType }
  | { type: ACTIONS.DELETE_CATEGORIES, payload: number }
  | { type: ACTIONS.SET_MODEL_ERRORS, payload: ModelErrorType[] }
  | { type: ACTIONS.SENDING_REQUEST }
  | { type: ACTIONS.REQUEST_COMPLETED };

export type State = {
  categories: CategoryType[];
  modelErrors: ModelErrorType[];
  loading: boolean;
};
```

I am trying to use ACTIONS value in the type that is,

```
 { type: ACTIONS.SET_CATEGORIES, payload: CategoryType[] }
```

But I am getting error which says `Cannot find namespace 'ACTIONS'.` . What am I doing wrong?

I tried couple of ways to fix this issue but none of them work. I am expecting to use the `ACTIONS.SET_CATEGORIES` value while defining the type for the Action. Basically this is for useReducer hook.

Answer (score 0):

Only a type can be assigned to a type. And `ACTIONS.SET_CATEGORIES` is not a type.

Rather try:

```js
 { type: typeof ACTIONS.SET_CATEGORIES, payload: CategoryType[] }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the fix was to use the enum,
Something like this,

```bash
export const enum ACTIONS {
  SET_CATEGORIES,
  ADD_CATEGORY,
  UPDATE_CATEGORY,
  DELETE_CATEGORY,
  SET_MODEL_ERRORS,
  SENDING_REQUEST,
  REQUEST_COMPLETED,
}


export type Action =
  | { type: ACTIONS.SET_CATEGORIES; payload: CategoryDisplayType[] }
  | { type: ACTIONS.ADD_CATEGORY; payload: CategoryDisplayType }
  | { type: ACTIONS.UPDATE_CATEGORY; payload: CategoryModelType }
  | { type: ACTIONS.DELETE_CATEGORY; payload: DeleteCategoryType }
  | { type: ACTIONS.SET_MODEL_ERRORS; payload: ModelErrorType[] }
  | { type: ACTIONS.SENDING_REQUEST }
  | { type: ACTIONS.REQUEST_COMPLETED };
```